# Trying to delete an entry in a table. Query doesn't delete the row, no idea how to debug

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to delete an entry in my database using the code below. The javascript function takes me to `index.php?delpost=` with the correct "adventureID" but when I check my database the row is still there. I've very recently started using PDO so I'm wondering if the `execute()` statement might be the issue. $dbh connect to my database at the top of the page and it is working as it prints every row from the table I'm trying to delete rows from. My goal is to successfully delete a row when I call the javascript function. The issue is - it doesn't.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function delpost(adventureID, title)
    {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete '" + title + "'" + " '" + adventureID + "'"))
        {
            window.location.href = 'index.php?delpost=' + adventureID;
        }
    }
</script>


<?php
    if(isset($_GET['delpost'])){
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM adventure WHERE adventureID = :adventureID");
        $stmt->execute(array(':adventureID' => $_GET['delpost']));
        header('Location: index.php?action=deleted');
        exit;
    }
?>


<?php
if(isset($_GET['action'])){
    echo '<h3>Post '.$_GET['action'].'.</h3>';
}

try {
    foreach($dbh->query("SELECT adventureID, title, postDate FROM adventure ORDER BY adventureID DESC") as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['title'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.date('jS M Y', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</td>';
        ?>

        <td>
            <a href="javascript:delpost('<?php echo $row['adventureID'] ?>','<?php echo $row['title'] ?>')">Delete</a>
        </td>

        <?php
        echo '</tr>';

    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: what does mysql say when you run the command?

Comment: If I run the command in phpMyAdmin it deletes the row

Comment: what does it return to the php?

Comment: move `try {` before `if(isset($_GET['delpost']))`

Comment: Replace your delete function with this: `var_dump($stmt->execute(array(':adventureID' => $_GET['delpost']))); die;` and post the result

Comment: @Pr0100 that didn't change anything either.

Comment: _"delete a row when I call the javascript function. The issue is - it doesn't."_ Does the javascript function execute or?

Comment: @KaloyanDoichinov how would I print out the result as I redirect the page?

Comment: @Epodax yes, it does. I get the confirmation window.

Comment: Well just comment out the redirect...

Comment: maybe You bind `'4'` intend `4`? `var_dump($_GET['delpost']);exit;`

Comment: Where does the var_dump appear?

Comment: Why do you not have a similar try - catch structure around the delete that you have around the select? Also, you should check the return value of your execute() call and if it returns false, then print out $stmt->errorInfo() with print_r()

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are facing problem with **MYSQL SAFE UPDATES** being ON. To avoid it and be able to finally delete rows, you can engage in the following tactics:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;

--- YOUR DELETE STATEMENT ---

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
```

To check if you have `SQL_SAFE_UPDATES` enabled you can do by running:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_safe_updates'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this code :

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM adventure WHERE adventureID = :adventureID");
$stmt->execute(array(':adventureID' => $_GET['delpost']));
```

By the following :

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM adventure WHERE adventureID = :adventureID"); 
$stmt->bindParam('adventureID', $_GET['delpost']);
$stmt->execute();
```

Explanation :

- You can either : Use ":variable" in your query, then pass variables by binding them with the "bindParam" function.
- Or : Use "?" in your query, and then pass variables in the "execute" function.

Full example can be found here : http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.execute.php#example-1050

Comment: Did you get any error ? Please try to be more explicit.

Comment: I didn't get any error. It just didn't work. I don't know how to print an error (if it appears) to the screen.

Comment: Do you have any log file ? Server log file ? And have you the "display_errors" in "on" ?

Comment: I don't know. Basically no.

Comment: Put ***ini_set("display_errors", "on")*** at the top of your PHP file. Then retry.

Comment: @YoussefElGharbaoui in the 2nd example on the page you linked, the parameters are named (:parametername format), yet the parameters are passed in the execute() call. The difference there is the way the parameters are passed: providing the parameter names as well.